# Join styled and normal string and keep formating

Tags: string-manipulation, style

I have a styled and a normal string and I want to join them. However, it seems that the styled object doesn't have the structure of a string and so they cannot be joined. I can do it with Print but I don't want to because I am preparing rather complicated output. See the example below.

[image]

Is there a work around?

Comment: Use `ToString[... , StandardForm]`.

Comment: it worked! Thanks! Can you explain why it works in the StandardForm?

Comment: Because this is the form where 2D syntax/coloring etc work. Check the last answer in the linked topic.